# com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.placeautocompletefragment is deprecated

Tags: android-fragments, location, deprecated, placeautocompletefragment

`placeautocompletefragment`is deprecated. I need an alternative code for the same.
Here's the code sample

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                destination = place.getName().toString();
                destinationLatLng = place.getLatLng();
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try migrating to 
com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment

There is more information here
https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#option_1_embed_an_autocompletesupportfragment